# awk to print a value from key value pair

Tags: awk, sed

I have below json and using awk to print value of concurrency but it is not giving any output

```
{
    "GlanceImages.list_images": [
        {
            "runner": {
                "type": "constant",
                "times": 10,
                "concurrency": 1
            },
            "context": {
                "users": {
                    "tenants": 2,
                    "users_per_tenant": 2
                },
                "images": {
                    "image_url": "http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.5/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img",
                    "disk_format": "qcow2",
                    "container_format": "bare",
                    "images_per_tenant": 4
                }
            },
            "sla": {
                "failure_rate": {
                    "max": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using awk

```
echo xyz.json | awk -F: '$1=="concurrency" {print $2}'
```

It doesnt give any output, what could be the issue. Ultimately I have to read multiple files and sum up all the values of concurrency and finally print the ultimate sum

Comment: Why aren't you using a JSON parser like jq?

Comment: Not an expert in jq but I tried and it gives output as null
`jq '.runner.concurrency' xyz.json`                           
`null`

Comment: To complete the question: as is mentioned in earlier (deleted) answers, the user has no access to `jq`. A bulletproof `awk` solution is requested.

Comment: Would this question not be an excellent duplicate? [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools). I'm very convinced you have access to python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another fragile script

```
$ awk '$1=="\"concurrency\":"{print $2}' file
```

if you have multiple matches you want to aggregate

```
$ awk '$1=="\"concurrency\":"{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file
```

Comment: this works thanks!!! but just wanted to check, if there is a better way to write below code (ignore variable names, it is just an example) 
`p=0
while read -r line do   var=$(awk '$1=="\"concurrency\":"{print $2}' $line)   echo $var   p=$(( $p+$var ))   echo "p is $p"   echo "$line" done < "$input"`

Comment: @SaurabhArora Yes but [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged. Accept the answer you got to the question you asked and then ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: Thanks @Karakfa that answers the question I had at first place but second answer would depend on case to case, since I have multiple files and need to add `concurrency` values across different files so this will not work, anyhow that answers the query I had. thanks!!!